# Is there a list of error codes available for verifyPhoneNumber function?

Tags: flutter, firebase

Have been trying to find this in the reference docs as well, although can't find the possible error codes. Link [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/verifyPhoneNumber.html). There are error codes available for other functions such as [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no specific error codes for phone number verification. It throws the same `FirebaseAuthException`, you can find the list [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors) like:

```
auth/invalid-phone-number
auth/phone-number-already-exists
```